# How to add TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy web part to site definition

Tags: web-part, site-definition, task-list

I am currently working on a site definition for a customer. Their wish is to create a team site with four subsites and some specified web parts on them.

Safe to say all that works, but I am however struggling with the attempt to deploy the site definition with a task and timeline web part.

By exploring a custom site template made through SharePoint 2013, I found out the web part that I want is a TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy [SPListTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) with value 171.

If you look at my onet.xml configuration, I have tried specifying that list and called it "Opgaver" (danish word for tasks) with type 171.

```
<Configuration ID="2" Name="ARN">
  <Lists>
    <List FeatureId="00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107" Type="171" Title="Opgaver" Url="Lists/Opgaver" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" QuickLaunchHeading="FALSE" />
  </Lists>
  <SiteFeatures>
```

In web features I activate the following features.

```
<WebFeatures>
    <!--TeamCollab Feature-->
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-4EA5-48D4-A4AD-7EA5C011ABE5" />
    <!--MobilityRedirect-->
    <Feature ID="F41CC668-37E5-4743-B4A8-74D1DB3FD8A4" />
    <!--Getting Started List instance-->
    <Feature ID="4AEC7207-0D02-4f4f-AA07-B370199CD0C7" />
    <!--MDS-->
    <Feature ID="87294C72-F260-42f3-A41B-981A2FFCE37A" />
    <!--HierarchyTasksList Feature-->
    <Feature ID="{f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0}" Name="FeatureDefinition/15/f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0" SourceVersion="1.0.20.0" />
    <!--TasksList Feature-->
    <Feature ID="{00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107}" Name="FeatureDefinition/15/00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107" SourceVersion="1.0.0.0" />
    <!--GanttTasksList Feature-->
    <Feature ID="{00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119}" Name="FeatureDefinition/15/00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119" SourceVersion="0.0.0.0" />
  </WebFeatures>
```

And in my module I am  trying to display that web part on the page.

```
<Module Name="ARNProject" Url="" Path="">
  <File Url="default.aspx">
    <!--Logo webpart-->
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="RightColumn" WebPartOrder="1">
      <![CDATA[
                    <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"
                         xmlns:iwp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Image">
                         <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                         PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                         <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart</TypeName>
                         <FrameType>None</FrameType>
                         <Title>Logo</Title>
                         <iwp:ImageLink></iwp:ImageLink>
                    </WebPart>
           ]]>
    </AllUsersWebPart><!--Timeline webpart-->
    <View List="171" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Body" WebPartOrder="1"/>
  </File>
</Module>
```

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Solved it following the answer below! I was using the wrong list feature ID...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the new Task list needs this feature to be activated:

```
f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0
```

I see you already have the feature in your SiteDefinition, but you will need to remove the `{}` surrounding it, and you can trim some of the other markup you have as well:

```
<!--HierarchyTasksList Feature-->
<Feature ID="f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0" />
```

Also this:

```
<Configuration ID="2" Name="ARN">
  <Lists>
    <List FeatureId="00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107" Type="171" Title="Opgaver" Url="Lists/Opgaver" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" QuickLaunchHeading="FALSE" />
  </Lists>
  <SiteFeatures>
```

should probably be (with the correct feature ID)

```
<Configuration ID="2" Name="ARN">
  <Lists>
    <List FeatureId="f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0" Type="171" Title="Opgaver" Url="Lists/Opgaver" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" QuickLaunchHeading="FALSE" />
  </Lists>
  <SiteFeatures>
```